# "fatal: no merge base found" Error when doing "git diff"

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am running

```
git diff --cached --name-status --no-ext-diff -z --diff-filter=ACDMRTUXB --ignore-submodules --relative origin/master --merge-base
```

But am getting the following error:

```
fatal: no merge base found
```

I have done some troubleshooting here

Before I do the git diff, I do a `git show-ref origin/master` and I can see in the response that origin/master

```
2017b29449b2a6c16802959b6c1aeda13cfa2bda refs/heads/origin/master
```

I can also see the list of branches - `git branch -a`

```
* (HEAD detached at origin/27f4b1cff972ae2f4e0bd19836ab4f7e771c474d)
  origin/master
  remotes/origin/27f4b1cff972ae2f4e0bd19836ab4f7e771c474d
```

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: it looks like you somehow have a *branch* named `27f4b1cff...`. This is bound to lead you into some issues. Can you add the list of branches defined on your remote ? `git ls-remote`

Answer (score 0):

This may happen with shallow clones (if your local repo is only a shallow clone of the remote repository), or if someone applied an action that rewrote the complete history of `origin/master` (for example: a `git filter-repo ...` on the complete history to remove some secret in the very first commit, or to enable git-lfs on past commits ...), or if you applied such an action on your local `master` branch.

In such cases : your local `master` and `origin/master` will not share any commit, so there won't be a so called "merge base".

---

Check the history of your repository to see if `master` and `origin/master` are related :

```
git log --oneline --graph master origin/master
```

You may add some details to your question to indicate if you managed to understand whether it is a shallow clone situation or a history rewrite.

Comment: Hi LeGEC, I am fetching origin/master like this:     git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ${SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN}" fetch origin master:origin/master --depth=2147483647

Comment: your `git fetch` command creates a local branch named `origin/master`. Drop the `:origin/master` from your command, and you will have a regular remote branch.

Comment: your repo does not have a local `master` branch, don't know if that is an issue.

Comment: what does `git log --oneline --graph HEAD` display ? can you explain how that repo was created ? (is it a persistent one ? or a repo created anew by a CI job ?)

Comment: Its fixed now- issue was Shallow fetch as you recommended. I changed the depth = 10000 and its working fine now.